# Regarding front door vrf concept

Tags: tunnel, gre

While reading up on front-door vrf concept [here](http://www.networkingwithfish.com/tunnels-and-the-use-of-front-door-vrfs/), i am just wondering , what if we made the network statements more precise/specific or used different subnets altogether, we would never have our tunnel go down due to `recursive routing`

Can you please confirm if this is a good approch to understanding `front-door vrf` concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to at least create static host routes pointing to the endpoint IPs of your tunnel to make sure they remain established.  Front door vrf is handy if your endpoint is using a dynamic IP address, forcing you to have a default route pointing out the internet circuit.  Splitting it into different vrfs allows you create a second default route pointing down a tunnel.

### Edit:

When you create a tunnel, you will have a source IP and destination IP for the tunnel.

[image: Show crypto isa sa]

If you want to avoid pointing your default route to your ISP (maybe you want to point down a tunnel instead), you will need at a minimum to create a host route for the tunnel destination IP address pointing to the ISP.

```
ip route 150.0.0.2 255.255.255.255 1.1.1.1
```

This way you can reach the other end of the tunnel.  Then you can point the default route down a tunnel and it won't break your tunnel.

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Tunnel0
```

But if you have spoke routers that have dynamic IP addresses which aren't known, you can't create a host route for them.  In this case you can create a front door vrf in order to use two default routes without breaking your tunnels.

You place your external interface into the new vrf.

```
Interface Gig0
ip vrf forwarding FRONT-DOOR
ip address x.x.x.x y.y.y.y
```

Then you can create a default route in that vrf used for establishing the tunnels.

```
ip route vrf FRONT-DOOR 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 z.z.z.z
```

You have to tell the tunnel interface to use the new vrf for establishing the tunnel.

```
Interface Tunnel0
tunnel vrf FRONT-DOOR
```

Now you can create a default route in the global routing table without interfering with the tunnel establishment.

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 a.a.a.a
```

Comment: I could not follow your answer,pardon my ignorance.Could you kindly explain using the diagram shown here https://www.packet-forwarding.net/tag/front-door-vrf/

Comment: See edits above.